Can people who have a high reputation answer a question and then close the question to prevent the question from being edited?
Often a question on Stack Exchange provides enough information about the motives and train of thought that enabled the question to be formulated that it's possible for people to raise objections to the exact formulation of the question.
On the other hand, being able to formulate an objection to exactly what was formulated doesn't necessarily enable one to replace the original question with a unique alternative.
Now, sometimes the problems with the original question are simple enough that an answer writer may simply respond to the answer writer's own interpretation of the question, without even bothering to ask what was intended.  In some cases, those problems might not even be noticed.
However, I can imagine that in other cases rethinking motivates some research and awareness of some considerations that were previously not even imagined.  If the original question starts undergoing a transformation that has no clear limits, then an answer writer may feel that the rug is being pulled out from under the answer writer.  Under those circumstances, it might be reasonable for an answer writer to try to get the question back to the form of it that elicited the answer writer's answer, and to close the question so that no more changes will be made.
Anyway, much of the above is pure speculation.  The question in the title occurred to me when I saw the following:
Why was Khomeini in France? Who allowed him to leave and why?
Although the question was closed, one answer got a score of 23 up-votes.  It would seem that, for participants in History Stack Exchange who want to increase their reputation or at least prevent their reputation level from going down, it would make a big difference whether or not closing a question would subtract from the answer writer's reputation what had been received from the answer.
That should at least explain why I included the tag "reputation."

Questions are quite editable after closure. Part of the point of the closure state is that the question may be edited into the kind of shape that would allow it to be reopened. Questions that are utterly irredeemable tend to get deleted instead.

Also, if you have meta-y questions about how the StackExchange software works in general, you'd probably be better off asking in meta.stackexchange.com. History.meta.com (this site) is really best used for questions specific to the History site. The people who hang out here aren't necessarily experts on the nuanced details about how StackExchange software itself works, whereas meta.stackexchange.com is exactly where such people hang out.

@T.E.D. "Questions are quite editable after closure. Part of the point of the closure state is that the question may be edited into the kind of shape that would allow it to be reopened."  Thank you, that's worth knowing.  In practice, isn't there a fairly high percentage of questions that, after being closed, remain closed?

T.E.D. has shared the simple answer (closed questions can still be edited) but there's a longer answer here - that even if they couldn't be, it wouldn't matter.
Good questions are better for rep
First of all, it takes 5 Close votes (or a moderator's Close) to close a question. A single high-rep user could not independently close a question.
But even if they did (or they had 4 like minded users play along) the returns would be remarkably slim - because the popularity of the question is what affects votes on answers. Good, popular questions appear in the Hot Network Questions sidebar. Bad, unpopular ones linger in ignominy.
A good question is defined by a good answer
Typically, questions get closed because they are not answerable - they're too broad, or aren't asking a question that historical methods can help with.
If there is already a highly rated answer, then by definition the question can be answered - and answered well. Even if the question gets closed, it's likely to be reopened in short order by another group of users.
I've seen this happen on other stacks - close wars between users who think it's a bad question and users who are answering it - but never wars between users who want to close it to prevent anyone else's answer and users who want to edit or answer it.
The closest analog that's an observed problem is the fastest gun in the west - Fastest Gun in the West Problem - where answers get frequently edited after submission in a race to be first before being good.
